# Textbox input right to left with minus sign "-" on left

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox to which I have applied style `direction:rtl;` since I want to type numbers in it. But when I add a minus sign `-` in it, it comes ahead of the numbers

[image]

I want it to be like the way we see normally

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: But numbers are written in LTR form

Comment: Use  style="text-align: right" to the input tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add **style="text-align:right;"** remove direction:rtl; from style

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. Dont know how I missed out on that. :)

Comment: it's my pleasure, sometimes we miss small things so no worries.

Answer (score 0):

the rtl direction property means "right to left", that's why is behaves like that.