# change money ; the minus sign on the right side

Tags: c#

i dont know why the minus sign go to the right side, i want to put the minus sign in left side but idk how

```
private void txtPM_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fee = lblFee.Text.Trim();
    string pm = txtPM.Text.Trim();

    decimal number = 0;
    decimal number2 = 0;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fee)) number = Convert.ToDecimal(fee);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pm)) number2 = Convert.ToDecimal(pm);

    decimal minus = number2 - number;
    txtChange.Text = minus.ToString().Trim();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textbox input right to left with minus sign "-" on left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507771/textbox-input-right-to-left-with-minus-sign-on-left)

Comment: How Currencies and other numbers are displayed, is part of a Format String. By default both Parse() and ToString() will retreive the format string from the Windows installation. This setting car varry greatly even between countries speaking the same language, and can be user defined too. Keep such a default behavior, you do not want to mess around with it.

Comment: What do you mean by *in left side but **idk** how*?

Comment: What are you culture settings?  How the string is formatted depends on that.

Comment: related to maccettura's question try replacing `txtChange.Text = minus.ToString().Trim();` with `txtChange.Text = minus.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Trim();` (also, i don't think you need the `.Trim()`)

Comment: i solve the problem guys, sorry i'm being dumb in my own program XD